# In Loving Memory of with comma or no comma?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, vocabulary

I am planning to write an engraved message behind an Ipad, which reads:

```
In Loving Memory of,
name of deceased
```

I am wondering if comma is needed here.

Comment: Why do you think you need a comma there?

Comment: @KillingTime Thanks for this, I have edited the post, cause I am actually going to the second line here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such an inscription should not have a comma, either in its one-line form or two-line form.  None of the functions of a comma, such as dividing a sentence or setting off parenthetical material, or indicating a short pause in recitation, is appropriate at that place in that inscription.

I cite as supporting evidence an exhaustive (OK, it took me 5 minutes) examination of images of headstones in English churchyards, courtesy of Google Images.

Comment: Thank you very much, much appreciated to get confirmation from this place. I will remove the comma.